# Truncate table in Realm Swift

Tags: swift, realm, truncate

I am trying to delete all objects inside one class. I found two possibilities inside Realms [documentation](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#deleting-objects). First there's the possibility to use `realm.deleteAll()`, which deletes the whole database and there's `realm.delete()`, which deletes one single object. Is there a way to delete all entries inside one Table/Class in a easy way?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Suppose you want to delete all objects of Notofications,

you can try this

```
let realm = Realm()
    realm.write {
      let allNotifications = realm.objects(Notifications)
      realm.delete(allNotifications)
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an extension that does this:

```
extension Object {
    static func deleteAll(`in` realm: Realm) throws {
        let allObjects = realm.objects(self)
        try realm.write {
            realm.delete(allObjects)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create deleteAll function

```
func deleteAll<T: Object>(_ data: [T.Type]) {
        let realm = try! Realm()
        realm.refresh()

        try? realm.write {
            for object in data {
                let allObjects = realm.objects(object)
                realm.delete(allObjects)
            }
        }
    }
```

Use this as -

```
deleteAll([OneClass.self, AnotherClass.self])
```